# When Our iPhone application get crashed

Tags: iphone, memory-management, crash

Tell me will our iPhone application crash because it is out of memory

(1)When it is using more memory than RAM has built in.

or

(2)It is independent of RAM Memory and crashes when application is taking memory than total iPhone which include secondary (virtual) memory.

Comment: there is no swap on the iPhone the system and all apps have to fit in RAM. However I'm not really sure what you're asking

Comment: I am asking if your app taking more memory than RAM then application get crashed or it will use virtual memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no virtual memory on the iPhone. The system and all apps have to fit in RAM. If your app starts to use a lot of memory and gets close to this limit you will be sent a memory warning.

The App Delegate will recieve

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
```

Most UIKit View Controllers will notify their child view controllers this has happened. This means that in your view controllers you will probably receive the message:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

There is also a notification posted that you can listen for

```
UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
```

In these methods you need to get rid of objects that may be taking up lots of memory that you dont need anymore like image caches and large bits of data.

If your app continues to consume memory then your app will be killed by the system. This will look like a crash to the user.

Comment: Thanks JackSlash for clarification i thought there is system which uses virtual memory

Comment: Cool. Well when someone answers your question on this website you need to accept their answer. To do that you click the outline of a tick next to the answer that worked for you. Welcome to Stack Overflow